# Remove configurations from unrelated environments when building a Grails WAR

Tags: security, grails, configuration

When building an environment-specific Grails WAR file configurations from other environments are included in the WAR file as well. For example, all the database connections properties from the production environment are also included in a WAR file built for test. Even though the configuration is compiled to class files it's quite simple to extract sensitive data from there.

In order to improve security, I want to exclude unrelated environment configurations from a WAR file. Is there a way to strip this configuration automatically during the WAR build or do I have to externalize these configurations and deploy them separately?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you could somehow analyse the bytecode and work out precisely which `Config$_closure3$_closure12` corresponds to the bit you don't need then you might be able to replace it in the war with an empty closure, but it's probably more hassle than it's worth. There's certainly no easy way I'm aware of.

I would put the config for each env in a separate file. If you put the prod config in web-app/WEB-INF/classes/myapp-prod.groovy (still in an environments block) and the dev config in a file in the top directory, and say

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:myapp-prod.groovy", "file:myapp-dev.groovy"]
```

then only the prod configuration will end up in the war. Though it would be completely human readable, so it may be more secure to simply leave the prod config directly in Config.groovy (so it gets compiled) and just use the external to override for dev mode.